# Regexp to capture comma separated values

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a string that can be a comma separated list of `\w`, such as:

- abc123
- abc123,def456,ghi789

I am trying to find a JavaScript regexp that will return `['abc123']` (first case) or `['abc123', 'def456', 'ghi789']` (without the comma).

I tried:

- `^(\w+,?)+$` -- Nope, as only the last repeating pattern will be matched, 789
- `^(?:(\w+),?)+$` -- Same story. I am using non-capturing bracket. However, the capturing just doesn't seem to happen for the repeated word

Is what I am trying to do even possible with regexp? I tried pretty much every combination of grouping, using capturing and non-capturing brackets, and still not managed to get this happening...

Comment: What's wrong with `string.split(',')`?

Comment: It will split according to ',', whereas I want to check that the matches comply with \w

Comment: What is the expected output for `=badstuff,goodstuff`? Do you have to deal with escaping mechanism in comma separated values?

Comment: Nope, no escaping necessary... just a 'no' in case it doesn't satisfy \w

Comment: So do you discard the whole input if anything is invalid? Or do you want to keep anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to discard the whole input when there is something wrong, the simplest way is to validate, then split:

```
if (/^\w+(,\w+)*$/.test(input)) {
    var values = input.split(',');

    // Process the values here
}
```

If you want to allow empty value, change `\w+` to `\w*`.

Trying to match and validate at the same time with single regex requires emulation of `\G` feature, which assert the position of the last match. Why is `\G` required? Since it prevents the engine from retrying the match at the next position and bypass your validation. Remember than ECMA Script regex doesn't have look-behind, so you can't differentiate between the position of an invalid character and the character(s) after it:

```
something,=bad,orisit,cor&rupt
          ^^             ^^
```

When you can't differentiate between the 2 positions, you can't rely on the engine to do a match-all operation alone. While it is possible to use a while loop with `RegExp.exec` and assert the position of last match yourself, why would you do so when there is a cleaner option?

---

If you want to savage whatever available, [torazaburo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25925797/1400768) is a viable option.

Answer (score 5):

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/lC3iO5/1)**

Try this regex :

```
'/([^,]+)/'
```

Alternatively, strings in javascript have a split method that can split a string based on a delimeter:

```
s.split(',')
```

Comment: I actually want to match \w specifically. So, I came up with ([\w]*,?) (which also doesn't force me to have a , at the end). Sounds good?

Comment: yup, but you don't need the `*` @Merc

Answer (score 0):

Split on the comma first, then filter out results that do not match:

```
str.split(',').filter(function(s) { return /^\w+$/.test(s); })
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex pattern separates numerical value in new line which contains special character such as `.`,`,`,`#` and so on.

```
var val = [1234,1213.1212, 1.3, 1.4]
var re = /[0-9]*[0-9]/gi;
```

Comment: What question are you answering?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "abc123,def456, asda12, 1a2ass, yy8,ghi789";
var re = /[a-z]{3}\d{3}/g;
var list = str.match(re);
document.write("<BR> list.length: " + list.length);
for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++) {
 document.write("<BR>list(" + i + "): " +  list[i]);
}
```

This will get only "abc123" code style in the list and nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

May be you can use **split** function

```
var st = "abc123,def456,ghi789";
var res = st.split(',');
```